# BeautifulSoup find and find_all not working as expect

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just starting using BeautifulSoup and I am encountering a problem. I set up a html snippet below and make a BeautifulSoup object:

```
html_snippet = '<p class="course"><span class="text84">Ae 100. Research in Aerospace. </span><span class="text85">Units to be arranged in accordance with work accomplished. </span><span class="text83">Open to suitably qualified undergraduates and first-year graduate students under the direction of the staff. Credit is based on the satisfactory completion of a substantive research report, which must be approved by the Ae 100 adviser and by the option representative. </span> </p>'
subject = BeautifulSoup(html_snippet)
```

I have tried doing several find and find_all operations like below but all I am getting is nothing or an empty list:

```
subject.find(text = 'A') 
subject.find(text = 'Research')
subject.next_element.find('A')
subject.find_all(text = 'A')
```

When I created the BeautifulSoup object from a html file on my computer before, the find and find_all operations were all working fine. However, when I pulled the html_snippet from reading a webpage online through urllib2, I am getting problems.

Can anyone point out where the issue is?

Comment: You don't have any nodes with text exactly equal to "A" or "Research" - you have nodes with a first word of `A` (or words beginning with A eg: `ae`) and another with research...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the argument like this:

```
import re
subject.find(text=re.compile('A'))
```

The default behavior for the [`text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) filter is to match on the entire body. Passing in a regular expression lets you match on fragments.

EDIT: To match only bodies beginning with `A`, you can use the following:

```
subject.find(text=re.compile('^A'))
```

To match only bodies containing words that begin with `A`, you can use:

```
subject.find_all(text = re.compile(r'\bA'))
```

It's difficult to tell more specifically what you're looking for, let me know if I've misinterpreted what you're asking.

Comment: Probably want word boundaries in there (at least I'm guessing that's what the OP really wants)

Comment: @JonClements I'm only seeing `Ae` in his sample text. Maybe he meant to match on the beginning of the body. I'll edit.

Comment: Probably best - there's a big difference between the word "A" and the capital letter "A" appearing in a line of text :) Anyway - this is bound to be the correct answer, so +1 from me

Comment: I was looking for matching words in the text and this worked for me.