# How to get outter most parent with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've gone through the BeautifulSoup documentation and found that the find_all method can find html based on the text parameter. 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument

Here's the code I have

```
        for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk:
            chunkHTML = htmlSoup.find_all(text=str(chunk))
            print chunkHTML
```

Chunks is a list that contains lines/phrases from the web page. My end goal is to get the tags that contain the specific chunks. When this code is executed it just prints empty lists. I've also made sure that the chunks that are in the list are present on the web page. I've also tried `chunkHTML = htmlSoup.find_all(string=str(chunk))` but it produces the same results.

While writing this question I ran into [BeautifulSoup find and find_all not working as expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585926/beautifulsoup-find-and-find-all-not-working-as-expect). I changed my code to

```
import re
    for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk:
            chunkHTML = htmlSoup.body.find_all(text=re.compile(str(chunk)))
            print chunkHTML
```

The above code does half the job and gets me all occurrences of the chunks. I would like to get the tag that contains this string. Example

```
<p>This is an element <a href="...">that contains some words</a>.</p>
```

Using the code from above:

```
chunkHTML = htmlSoup.body.find_all(text=re.compile('some words'))
print chunkHTML
```

The desired output is:

```
<p>This is an element <a href="...">that contains some words</a>.</p>
```

EDIT: I updated the question to be specific to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
    for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk:
            chunkHTML = htmlSoup.body.find_all(text=re.compile(re.escape(chunk)))
            if len(chunkHTML) > 0:
                print chunkHTML[0].parent
                print "\n"
```

This is how I ended up implementing the solution. With re.compile I had to do re.escape since the text I was trying to find was "unknown" and could potentially contain text/symbols that could change the Regular Expression. After that I used `chunkHTML[0].parent` to get the complete element.

From @宏杰李's answer that he linked to I see that `.previous_element` works the same way as `.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [16]: html = '''<p>This is an element <a href="...">that contains some words<
    ...: /a>.</p>'''

In [17]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

In [18]: soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=="p" and "some words" in tag.text)
Out[18]: <p>This is an element <a href="...">that contains some words</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution does work with the example provided but I'm working on a general solution where I don't know the tag that the chunk may be in.